# Can't install Ubuntu try almost all the way get error: end Kernel panic

Tags: boot, system-installation, nomodeset

I checked everything I found in internet and nothing worked in my situation.

I tried to install Ubuntu on my PC. I download Ubuntu 16.04 and put the iso on my USB drive with Universal USB Installer. When I press Install Ubuntu after 2 minute show `end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)` error on black screen

[image]

This error appears after I press Install Ubuntu on installing screen

Note: Window 7 is installed on my PC and work properly. I installed Ubuntu that is in my USB in my Laptop without any issue.

What I've tried:

- Try to bootable with Rufus and it's not work same error the difference is the installation page is purple and has some extra options. If I press F2 I can change language and if I press F6 I can choice some boot options. I choice acpi=off and nomodeset but nothing change same error. If I use Universal USB Installer, Ubuntu install screen is black and just Tab key work and it's show some text end up with quite splash --- . I try to add nomodeset in the end of this text.
- I try to install with mini.os (installing from Internet) that doesn't work same error.
- I try even another Linux distro none of them work.
- I try wubi to install ubuntu inside windows. In this way Ubuntu installation process start (in graphical mode) but it's end up with errors (I don't like to use wubi)
- The only distro I can install is Debian and not in a normal way I can install Debian with debian net installer. I want to install ubuntu so I'm writing these.

I's been almost 10 hours I'm trying to install Ubuntu and I'm not succeed yet.
So anyone can help I will be appreciative.

PC Hardwares Info:

- CPU: Intel Dual
- GPU: Nvida 512MB :-(
- RAM: 2GB

Comment: Sorry about the grammar English isn't my mother language.

Comment: Thanks Danibix. I'm not trying to upgrade kernel, I'm trying to install ubuntu.

Comment: What version are you trying to install? I heard 17.10 has bugs so you need `17.10.1` instead.

Comment: you need to show us a little bit more ... what is the error given for "unable to mount root file system. Is the HDD controler set for IDE or AHCI?